# core data and paging

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a database of 50,000 records.  I'm using core data to fetch records from a search.  A search could return 1000 records easily.  What is needed  to page through these records using core data and uitableview?  I would like to show 100 records at a time and have 'load more' button after viewing 100 records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the NSFetchRequest and its controls over batches.  You can set the batch size and the offset which will allow you to "page" through the data.